# curl with empty space url

Tags: php, curl

there is a file, its name contain empty space.
ex) hello I am good.zip

I am trying to read the file using curl.

so, the url should be like this:

```
http://domain.com/hello I am good.zip
```

but, curl can not seems to read that kind of file names.
because url is not right format.

So, Is there another way to read the file using curl?
Or some options that I didn't know?

server lang is php.
and my curl code is below:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$url = str_replace(" ","%20",$url); // to properly format the url 

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
```

Comment: I was thinking that is a space related problem, but I was unsure. Only files with spaces in their filenames were not downloaded. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Where ever there's a `space` use `%20`, that should do the trick, hopefully.

so it will become:

```
http://domain.com/hello%20I%20am%20good.zip
```

This will hopefully do the trick.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

try using `urlencode('http://domain.com/hello I am good.zip');`
or `http://domain.com/'.urlencode('hello I am good.zip')`;